# Graph api Update event not working properly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am sending a patch request with below details on created event, but it is updating the isOnlineMeeting value to true and false randomly. I am loosing the teams joining link.

{"subject":"Test55","isOnlineMeeting":true,"body":{"contentType":"HTML","content":"Does noon work for you1?"}}

What could be the issue?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue, I have tested it in POSTMAN and it worked perfectly for me when I set isonlinemeeting to true it gave me the link in the event item and if I give it as false it removed the link. Can you give a try with POSTMAN or Graph Explorer?

Comment: I have tested in Graph explorer and it is switching between online and offline event for each continuous request. It is happening when we are sending multiple parameters in request body. If we send only one property like subject it is working fine. Execute the request multiple times and see the change in response.

Comment: we are also experiencing this issue

Comment: @MaheshkumarChiliveri to keep the link don't update the Body, then it will work. See [this thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10618).

Comment: @Nth.gol try the same as suggested above.

Comment: will check and let you know

Comment: @Nth.gol it is the issue with update of body of the meeting. When we create an event, Body(Agenda) will be saved in an html form. In update of the event, when you update body of the meeting with a text, the html of body will be overwritten with the plain text and event will be updated to offline meeting. Initially i thought this should be handled internally but that is the not case with the event api.

Comment: Whenever I want to update the body of the event, I have to get the existing agenda and update that html with new agenda and update the event with updated html.

Comment: On outlook end, the online meeting properties are cleaned up if the teams meeting blob is removed from the body.  Please try the same after removing body in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I also reproduce the issue. Solution doesn't allow update of body after creating  Online meetting. I found a way to PATCH body: you can write the URL of TeamsMeeting into the body, then the online meeting is preserved.